# Засевать и засеивать чем-то принципиально отличаются (кроме плюс-минус буквы)?

Tags: выбор-слов

> У археологов прошлого века вошло в моду сохранять растения на их
>   привычных местах, отслеживать их рост и, в случае обнаружения в ранних
>   слоях зёрен или пыльцы, даже вновь засеивать древние улицы и площади
>   исконными травами, кустарниками и цветами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что особых (принципиальных) различий между этими глаголами нет.
Вот что пишет [Большой толковый словарь русских глаголов](https://verbs_ru.academic.ru/1184/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C):
**засева́ть** и **засе́ивать**, несов. (сов. засе́ять), *что*. Помещать (поместить) семена растений в почву, занимая ими какой-либо участок земли.

*На целине обычно засеивали новь только следующей весной. Весной участок перед домом бабушка засеивала разными цветами. Степан засеял поле пшеницей.*

В словаре Ушакова:
**засе́ивать**, -аю, -аешь, несов. (к засеять), что. То же, что засевать.